# Google Map API v3 example from their site doesn't work without an API key but does with a Key. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polyline, google-polyline

**Problem:** I am trying to use a sample of Google Map API v3 without an API key and it doesn't render. (It does render if I use a key).Anyone know why?

I decided to use this example 
(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple)

In order to make it work without a key I replaced this script:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"></script>
```

with this other script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

This is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple Polylines</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

// This example creates a 2-pixel-wide red polyline showing the path of William
// Kingsford Smith's first trans-Pacific flight between Oakland, CA, and
// Brisbane, Australia.

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {lat: 0, lng: -180},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });

  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
    {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
    {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
    {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
}

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't render. Any idea what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: In addition to a more fleshed out example, are you getting particular js errors?

Comment: @Locke125 no particular errors. It is for sure the script about the google API key because when i replace that bit with a maps API key it works

Comment: The [posted code renders a map for me without a key](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/z0ancwy6/), did you really remove the `callback=initMap` from the API include?  That would prevent the `initMap` function from ever being called and you would need to add code to call it on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the google maps script include into the head. It has to be included before you call it.

Call your initMap function to run the function you set up. The `function initMap()` has only been defined, but you haven't run it until then.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple Polylines</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

// This example creates a 2-pixel-wide red polyline showing the path of William
// Kingsford Smith's first trans-Pacific flight between Oakland, CA, and
// Brisbane, Australia.

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {lat: 0, lng: -180},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });

  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
    {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
    {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
    {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
}

initMap();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You are awesome :D